# print panel as sheet view instead modal view

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf, printing

i have this solution to print a pdf file with swift 3 for osx.

```
let dictDocuments = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
let completePath = dictDocuments.appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: completePath!)

let printInfoDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: NSPrintInfo.shared().dictionary())
printInfoDict.setObject(NSPrintSpoolJob, forKey: NSPrintJobDisposition as NSCopying)
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printInfoDict as! [String : Any])

printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
printInfo.scalingFactor = 1.5


let printOp = pdfDocument!.printOperation(for: printInfo, scalingMode: .pageScaleNone, autoRotate: true)!
```

but now i would like to show the print dialog as a sheet view.

i tried something like this:

```
let printPanel = NSPrintPanel()
printPanel.beginSheet(with: printInfo, modalFor: self.view.window!, delegate: self, didEnd: nil, contextInfo: nil)
```

the print dialog will shown as a sheet view, but without the pdf file.
logically: i did not assign the pdf file. but how can i do this?

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `NSPrintOperation` for a method to show the print panel as sheet?

Comment: i did not find any information to show the print panel as sheet: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprintoperation

Comment: Try `runModal(for:delegate:didRun:contextInfo:)`.

Comment: ahhhh thanks. i searched for "sheet". didn't know that runModal do the same